# OpenID, Express, React - sending obtained token by authentication from backend to frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, openid

after authentication user gets redirected to `/auth/steam/authenticate` with data stored in url which are being saved to **JWT Token** using function  `steam.authenticate`, after this I am trying to redirect user to my frontend with **token** but I don't know how to handle that request in my frontend since I am not sending request from it.

**GOAL:** Save user token in my frontend as a cookie.

```
app.get("/auth/steam/authenticate", (req, res) => {
  try {
    steam.authenticate(req.url).then((user) => {
      const token = jwt.sign(user._json, process.env.JWT_TOKEN);
      return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/"); //Frontend
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```